# how to compare more than two Strings in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have 4 strings s1,s2,s3,s4. and i want to compare it with "yes","no" and "both"
It has to be like `(s1.equals("yes"));`

1. if ALL strings are equal to "yes" it should give one result.
2. if ALL strings are equal to "no" it should give one result.
3. if any 2 strings are equal to "yes" and another 2 strings are equal to "no" it has to give one result.
4. if any 3 strings are equal to "yes" and 1 string equal to "no" it has to give one result.
5. if any 3 stings are equal to "no" and 1 string is equal to "yes" it has to give one result..

How to do this comparison?

Comment: Are they only ever "yes" or "no"?

Comment: I would recommend storing a count of the strings that match either 'yes' or 'no', then determining the result based off the counts.

Answer (score 7):

I would store those strings in a list, and use `Collections` utility to find the frequencies of `yes` and `no`. Then apply your conditions to number of `yes` and `no`.: -

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("yes"); add("yes"); add("no"); add("no");
}};

int yes = Collections.frequency(list, "yes");
int no = Collections.frequency(list, "no");


if (yes == 4 || yes == 0) {   // all "yes" or all "no"
    System.out.println("Operation 1");

} else if (yes == 2) {   // 2 "yes" and 2 "no"
    System.out.println("Operation 2");

} else {   // (1 "yes", 3 "no") or (1 "no", 3 "yes")
    System.out.println("Operation 3");
}
```

Of course, I assume that your strings can only be `"yes"` or `"no"`.

Comment: Thanks! well one more strings is there "both".

Comment: @Learner678. You mean, now you have `"yes"`, `"no"` and `"both"`?

Comment: yeah 3 strings, `yes` `no` and `both`

Comment: @Learner678.. You can extend the above method to your desired input, and different conditions, like, 2 "both", 3 "yes", and 4 "no". Of course there can be any number of conditions, which you have to specify first.

Comment: This is a poor impl. Sure it works, but it's complete overkill. There are a couple of ways to do this in one line. If I was reviewing this bloated line-heavy and instance creation heavy impl I would instantly reject it and ask the programmer to do it again. I can't understand why people have voted this answer so highly. One of the hallmarks of poor code is there's a lot of it. , and this code is no exception.

Comment: @Bohemian.. I would like to have you point out some reasoning on the basis of which you have said all this. Of course your solution is a clever one. But you should really benchmark your code and mine.

Comment: @Bohemian.. You will be surprised to hear that, this code is approx 10 times faster than yours, when I ran both of them for `100000` times.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this logic. This one does what you intend to do :

```
if(s1.equals("yes") && s2.equals("yes") && s3.equals("yes") && s4.equals("yes"))
    result1;
else if (s1.equals("no") && s2.equals("no") && s3.equals("no") && s4.equals("no"))
    result2;
else if ((s1.equals("yes") || s2.equals("yes")) && (s3.equals("no") || s4.equals("no")))
    result3;
else if((s1.equals("yes") || s2.equals("yes") || s3.equals("yes")) && s4.equals("no"))
    result4;
else if((s1.equals("no") || s2.equals("no") || s3.equals("no")) && s4.equals("yes"))
    result5;
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it doesn't cover all permutations of values: e.g. it fails for `yes/no/no/no` - 'if *any* 3 stings are equal to "no" and 1 string is equal to "yes"'

Comment: What do you mean ? I have covered the permutations that the OP mentioned in his Qs. How does it not cover all of them ?

Comment: `yes/no/no/no` is not the same as `no/no/no/yes` (the number of combinations does not yield a "trivial conditional")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are either "yes" or "no", use this:

```
int yesCount = (s1+s2+s3+s4).replace("no", "").length() / 3;
```

Then base your logic on that, possibly with a `switch(yesCount)`

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] str={s1,s2,s3,s4};
int yesCount=0, noCount=0;
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
if("yes".equals(str[i]))
yescount++;
else if("no".equals(str[i]))
noCount++;
}
String check=""+yesCount+noCount;
switch(check){
case "40":
//do whatever
break;
case "30":
//do whatever
break;
case "20":
//do whatever
break;
case "10":
//do whatever
break;
case "31":
//do whatever
break;
case "21":
//do whatever
break;
case "11":
//do whatever
break;
case "22":
//do whatever
break;
case "12":
//do whatever
break;
case "13":
//do whatever
break;
case "04":
//do whatever
break;
case "00":
//do whatever
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming string value can be either yes or no

```
    int result = 0;
    if("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(s0)) result++;
    if("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(s1)) result++;
    if("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(s2)) result++;
    if("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(s3)) result++;
    switch(result){
        case 0:
            System.out.println("all strings are NO");
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("3 strings are NO, 1 string is YES");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("2 strings are NO, 2 strings are YES");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("1 string is NO, 3 strings are YES");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("all strings are YES");
            break;
    }
```